# Is it meaningful to construct explicit feedback collaborative filtering based rec system in my scene?

Tags: collaborative-filtering, matrix-factorization

I am confused about which one of implicit and explicit feedback is suitable for my scene. I tend to make a practical rec-system for my company(e-commerce) which has 14Million customers and 10 million products. But the explicit rating data only covers 2.2M customers and 1.5M products. 
There are 10.7Million customers made purchase on 3.7Million products over the past 1 years.
So what confuse me is that constructing explicit feedback based rec system is meaningful ?

Answer (score 1):

the answer is both yes and no, and well, it depends! Mostly, it depends on what the objective of your recommender system is, and how you will be delivering the recommendations to the customers. In either case, you will have the cold-start problem to solve, and so the numbers you provide don't have much influence on your decision.

**Explicit Feedback**

- Will always have less data available
- Data is in general more useful since it is a cleaner signal
- Makes showing predictions to customers easy (think stars in Netflix)

**Implicit Feedback**

- Will always have more data available, but almost never data for every customer and product
- Data likely to be noisier, but not necessarily less useful
- Can still provide brilliant recommendations, but it is harder to explain why recommendations were made to customers. This usually isn't a requirement though.

**The Real Answer**

Look at your problem in detail, and construct a hypothesis around what will be good. Define a way of measuring good (Google "evaluating a recommender system" for ideas), and implement this evaluation. Get experimenting! Try both approaches, get a feel for what works and what doesn't. Most importantly, try to figure out why something works or it doesn't. Within a week or two you should start to get a good feel for what matters to your companies customers, and you will get more ideas. Probably, you will want to use both implicit and explicit, and combine them somehow (Google "hybrid recommender systems").

Comment: thanks. I will read your references. It seems that there is not too much papers talking about how to apply implicit feedback dataset for CF.